# one single image url for an avatar to display random image from a folder (server-side php script)

Tags: php, image, rotator

a long time ago i once did found a php script that contained only about 6 short lines of it if i remember correctly. Yet no luck, i couldn't find anything like that anymore, so i am gonna ask for help from you.

It was only one file "rotate.php" and a folder that contained all by myself chosen images, the script was supporting different dimensions and with different extensions (jpg, png, gif) as i remember.

Script generated one single url that could be used as an image url for an avatar or between [img] tags on forums with bbcode support.

Respectively, when someone visits my forums profile or sees my comment on forums, per every visit/refresh it always shows a random image as my avatar.

There seems to be many simple variations to create a random image slideshow for my own websites logo or something, but i can't figure a way to make it work for external sites like with previously mentioned single url.

Give me some hope, thanks.

Comment: how about learning php?

Comment: We're not going to provide a solution for you. However, we will help you if/when you get stuck along the way. Put in some effort to write some code and ask for our help when you run into issues.

Comment: That's very helpful.. i am already learning javascript basics, but with work in other spheres i have no much free time to put into it. About 6 short lines, i was hoping someone already have a solution to share..

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps, you can use PHP inbuilt function called `opendir($path)` to open the folder in path  and read the directory.

```
   <?php
        function getImagesFromDir($path) {
            $images = array();
            if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
                while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
                    // checks for gif, jpg, png
                    if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                        $images[] = $img_file;
                    }
                }
                closedir($img_dir);
            }
            return $images;
        }

        function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
            mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); // php 4.2+ not needed
            $num = array_rand($ar);
            return $ar[$num];
        }

        $path = 'imagesfolder/';    

        $imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);
        $img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);

     ?>
```

IN HTML:

```
      <img src="<?php echo $path . $img; ?>" alt="" />
```

Ref: http://www.dyn-web.com/code/basics/random_image/random_img_php.php

Comment: I have seen this, but how to turn the last line into one url that can be used on external sites with no support of html, but bbcode only?

Comment: @family-guy You will need to upload a script like the one mentioned above, then link your images, using BBcode like `[img]url-of-script[/img]`.

Comment: But bbcode doesn't support image url that doesn't end with image extension. Look example. http://i.imgur.com/INLQro3.jpg    - on my own host script's url should look something like that and being able to show random image per every visit/refresh.